# How does a country increases or decreases it currency value (exchange rate) against other nations currency?

Tags: currency, money-supply, international-economics

I want to know how a country, Mexico for instance, keeps the exchange rate higher or lower against other nations currency, USD, EUR, JPY. How does the value of a nation currency is valued against other counties?

Comment: Are you asking how a country manages a currency exchange rate? Or are you asking why they manage to a particular target? Or something else?

Comment: @BKay how a country manages a currency exchange rate.

Comment: You may find this answer about the recent Swiss franc helpful:
http://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/3108/what-did-the-swiss-national-bank-use-to-purchase-eur-while-pegging-the-franc-to/3109#3109

Comment: I found this series of videos very informative and answered my question.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=itoNb1lb5hY